# Use of Admin using Devise gem over Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

How to use admin role using devise gem.

Can we same controller for admin and users using devise gem.

In Cancan we can use same controller for all roles.

Which gem is good for admin releated aspects.

Anyone tell me example of admin aspects using devise gem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) Or [RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin). Both of them have nice ways to use cancan. If you confused about whether to use then decide by evaluating the following :

If you think you dont want to give that much effort and you need only CRUD staffs then use `RailsAdmin`.

Otherwise Use `ActiveAdmin`